# I am trying to download a file which is returned as FileStream or Byte Array using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I am getting a Response from Post method, which has byte array or filestream one of the other be there, I want to download the file in a react component which has button, on button click. If I write the file on to the Server then access it from React, I am able to download the same file, but when I am trying to download the same using byte array, its saying correct file - any help please - thank you.

Comment: Try to use FileReader constructor

Comment: Is filereader available in react. I'm writing the file on clients machine using React or JavaScript Can i actually? Can you please elaborate a little bit thank you for the comment.

Comment: When I checked the length of the array on the Server it is: 113175
and on at the client it is: 150900, why is client side the array length is more IDK - any idea please?